# Semicolon vs em-dash in response thanking someone for help

Tags: semicolons, em-dashes

I want to thank someone for helping me. I am trying to decide which of these is more appropriate:

- Thanks for the clarification; that was helpful.
- Thanks for the clarification – that was helpful.

What is the difference between these, and which one is more appropriate?

It seems to me that one phrase (the em-dash one) is focused on the *clarification* being the object that is helpful, whereas the other phrase (the semicolon one) is focused on possibly *the thing that the clarification is addressing* being helpful. Obviously, my intention here is for the *clarification* to be regarded as helpful. Am I correct in my thinking here?

Comment: Insignificant difference; perhaps the dash signals a lengthier pause in reading, adding emphasis to the 'that was helpful' statement. No change in meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought the *semicolon* was meant to signal a lengthier pause, since it signals more "detachment" between the clauses (it's meant to be used between two independent clauses)? And that's part of why I thought the em-dash would place more emphasis on the clarification being the object that is helpful.

Comment: No. See the extract in the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [The Narrative Arc_Andrea Cranford](https://thenarrativearc.org/blog/2020/2/4/epic-grammar-battle-semicolon-versus-em-dash)  (Crawford is a professional copywriter and copyeditor):

> **Should you use an em-dash or a semicolon?**
>
> The difference between an em-dash and a semicolon is the length and
> purpose of the pause it creates. An em-dash isolates the idea that
> follows; a semicolon combines two ideas into one. The best way to
> determine if you can use an em-dash or a semicolon is to try them both
> out in your sentence, then read it aloud. Listen for the beats and
> determine which conveys your point the best.

[Notes:

A Cranford goes on to analyse three sentences, stating her opinion on which choice is better in each, and why.

B Her article uses the em-dash here reflecting US usage, whereas many in the UK use a spaced en-dash in place of this usage.

C1 The dash, signalling a lengthier pause than the semicolon, separates to a considerable degree, the semicolon combines more, though not as much as a comma where one is possible.

C2 While certain sentences may work better with one or the other, one usually has a choice between the semicolon and the dash (and the colon and ellipsis should not be forgotten).

C3 There is rarely if ever a change in meaning forced by a change in such punctuation (between independent clauses), and none in the example in the question.]